# How can I check specific macro is there or not with identifier stored inside NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have macros named

```
CONSTANT_1
CONSTANT_2
CONSTANT_3
CONSTANT_4 etc..
```

I have an **NSString** variable sending from another class consist of macro name only, how can I access the contents of macro variable matching with this NSString.

My NSString variable is defined as:

```
NSString *str=@"CONSTANT_3"
```

Comment: To further clarify: You require those to be defines for some reason? Instead of real constants, I mean? And furthermore, the defines cannot be of the form `@"whatever"`, so that your variable could just be `NSString *str = CONSTANT_3` (i.e. you could leave out the @ and "")? DashAndRest's answer perfectly solves the issue, but the entire thing smells like weird design to me in the first place...

Answer (score 4):

**1 Here is one solution to do it, but it needs you to know all macros:**

```
#define CONSTANT_1 1
#define CONSTANT_2 2
#define CONSTANT_3 3

#define STRINGIZE(x) #x

+ (int)getValueForContant:(NSString *)constantStr {
    const char *charStr = STRINGIZE(CONSTANT_1);
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:charStr];
    if ([constantStr isEqualToString:str]) {
        return CONSTANT_1;
    }

    charStr = STRINGIZE(CONSTANT_2);
    str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:charStr];
    if ([constantStr isEqualToString:str]) {
        return CONSTANT_2;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

And use it as:

```
int constVal = [ClassName getValueForContant:@"CONSTANT_1"];
```

It'll give you `int` value in return.

**2 Use `.plist` to define constants** and loop through to get appropriate value as provided string parameter to this method;

```
+ (int)getValueForContant:(NSString *)constantStr
```

Comment: I'd say this is a/the canonical answer indeed, but it still makes my eyes bleed and the baby Jesus weep... :D Well done though, DashAndRest! Never thought this was possible at the same time (correct, yet still somehow depressing-looking code)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to better use constants

```
NSString *const CONSTANT_1 = @"1";
NSString *const CONSTANT_2 = @"2";
NSString *const CONSTANT_3 = @"3";
```

The you could use `CFBundleGetDataPointerForName`

```
-(NSString *)valueOfConstantWithName:(NSString *)constantName {
    void ** pointer = CFBundleGetDataPointerForName(CFBundleGetMainBundle(),   (__bridge CFStringRef)constantName);
    return (__bridge NSString *)(pointer ? *pointer : nil);
}
```

and use that method like

```
NSString *costant1 = [self valueOfConstantWithName:@"CONSTANT_1"];
```